# Description of a constraint for a mixed integer program.

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming

Suppose we have 100 items that are labelled from the set $P = \{A, B, C, D, E\}$. My constraints are as follows:

1. I want to choose exactly seven items.
2. The choice should have at least one item of each type (covers five choices).
3. The sixth choice can be either $D$ or $E$.
4. The seventh choice can be either of the labels.

I was trying to pose this problem as an integer programming problem where I am looking for a $100\times1$ column vector $x \in \{0,1\}$. Each element $x_i$ in $x$ represents whether the item corresponding to $x_i$ is chosen or not.

I am thinking of assigning integers to different labels in the set $P$, but currently unable to perceive how can this be turned into a constraint of the form $c^Tx$, where $c$ is a column vector.

Is this the right way to solve this problem? If yes, can you please explain how to create such a constraint equation. If not, can you please suggest an alternative method.

Comment: What is your goal ? What kind of result you wish to have after the calculations ?

Comment: @calculus I will try to answer your question as I understood it. I want to come up with a vector $x$ that will satisfy these constraints. Are you asking about the real-life application of this problem ?

Comment: But what does x represent ? Could you give me (us) a possible numerical solution (with explanation) ? And it is known how many items with lable A,B,C,D or E are among the 100 items ? If I understand it right there will be several possible solution. Does the order of drawing play a role ?

Comment: @calculus The assumptions are i). Labels are such that at least one such combination exists that satisfies all these constraints. No the order does not matter. As I mentioned, the constraint formulation will be used in an integer program to maximize some objective function. Therefore, despite there will be many such combinations that satisfy these constraints, the program will output the one that has maximum value of the objective function.

Comment: Do you know, what the objective function is ? I don´t want to annoy you. I just want to understand the problem.

Comment: @calculus a number is associated with each label to show its cost. The objective function is the sum of the costs of all the seven chosen items.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define variable $x_{i,j}$ to be 1 if the $i$th item is the $j$th item in the set $P$.

**Constraint 1:**

$$\sum_j x_{i,j} = 1 \quad \forall i$$

ensures we pick something for each "slot" $i$.

**Constraint 2:**

$$\sum_i x_{i,j} \geq 1 \quad \forall j$$

ensures we pick at least one of each item $j$

**Constraint 3:**

$$x_{6,4} + x_{6,5} == 1$$

I assume it mean it has to be either D or E.

**Constraint 4:**

This doesn't need any extra inequalities.

Comment: The constraint 4 is that the seventh choice can be $A$, $B$, $C$, $D$ or $E$, i.e., any of the labels.

Comment: In the case of your solution, the unknown is a matrix $X$ instead of a column vector $x$. Since I am using MATLAB to solve this problem that gives solution in the form of a vector, how should I incorporate your formulation to suit MATLAB [GLPK](http://kam.mff.cuni.cz/~elias/glpk.pdf) or MATLAB [intlinprog](http://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/intlinprog.html).

Comment: Constraint 4 doesn't seem to need anything extra then.

Comment: You can just flatten the matrix down to a vector, i.e. map the two dimensions into a vector of length 35

Comment: @IanDunning In the formulation of constraint 3, you have defined the constraint for the sixth item only. I assume $i \in \{1,2,\ldots,100\}$. If you meant that $ i \in \{1,2,\ldots,6\}$, how will I know which of the seven out of 100 items are chosen?

Comment: You are picking 7 items, right? $i$ is the $i$th item you pick, and $j$ is the type/label of that item. I'm assuming there are at least 7 of each item type, so the fact there are 100 total items to pick from doesn't matter (although it'd be easy to add a cosntraint for that)

Comment: thanks for your patience. May be I am unable to understand you, and I try once more to explain myself. Suppose we get the following matrix solution 
$$ X = \begin{matrix} \\left[
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\ 
0 & 1 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 & 0 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
1 & 0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\right]\\
\end{matrix} $$
Now how will we know that which of the 7 out of 100 items have been chosen? My objective is to find the index of the items. For example, a sample solution could be the set of 2nd, 5th, 19th, 29th, 34th, 89th and 90th items.